Simplifying Exp[I Mod[x, 2π]] to Exp[I x]
I have an expression involving
Exp[I Mod[x,2Pi]]

I think it can be simplified to
Exp[I x]

How can I convince Mathematica to do so?
I tried Simplify, but also Refine using Element[x, Reals].

It is simplified to Exp[I x] when x is an integer actually

Mathematica assumes quantities are complex, by default. What would Mod[x, 2*Pi] means for complex x? You need to tell Mathematica that you are assuming x is a real number.

@march I think the standard def. is $z_1 \equiv z_2 \bmod a$ iff $(z_2-z_1)/a \in {\Bbb Z}$. OTOH, whiile Mod[] is defined for complex numbers, it does not give a residue equivalent under this definition. It seems to consider the numbers equivalent if the quotient lies in the Gaussian integers (${\Bbb Z} + i,{\Bbb Z}$). The OP's expressions are not equivalent under this definition of Mod[], but they are under what I called the standard one.

Use FindInstance to search for counter-examples, e.g., FindInstance[Exp[I Mod[x, 2 Pi]] != Exp[I x], x, 5] That will lead you to add the assumption that x is real.

Turning my comment into an answer
Exp[I Mod[x, 2 Pi]] // 
 FullSimplify[#, Assumptions -> {x ∈ Reals}] &

returns the desired result.
Thanks to @march for the comment!

Change Integers to Reals, and it still works, as it should.

@march Thanks for this !

Simpler: Exp[I Mod[x, 2 Pi]] // FullSimplify[#, x ∈ Reals] & because the second argument of FullSimplify is assumed to be the assumptions.
